# Merge 2 different tables without repeating values PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have 2 tables; the first one is [user_in_event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbn6W.jpg) table

which here role can be `regular, waiting for ack or moderator`

and the second one is [user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNM02.jpg) table

Here the role can be `regular or admin`

I want to take the role from user_in_event table, based on the event_id and output all users info (beside user role) and output in a single JSON

I have tried to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
$query = "SELECT user_in_event.role, user_in_event.user_id, user.name, user.email, user.birthday, user.phone_number, user.address, user.image
                    FROM user LEFT JOIN user_in_event 
                    ON user_in_event.event_id = '".$event_id."' 
                    LIMIT $num_of_rows";


        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)
         or die(mysqli_error($con));

        // print_r($query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $response[] = $row; 
        }




    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
```

but I got messed up data

```
[
  {
    "role": "moderator",
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "ofir",
    "email": "ofir@ofr.com",
    "birthday": "08/12/2016",
    "phone_number": "123",
    "address": "yoqneam",
    "image": "http://imgur.com/a/KslOW"
  },
  {
    "role": "waiting for ack",
    "user_id": "21",
    "name": "ofir",
    "email": "ofir@ofr.com",
    "birthday": "08/12/2016",
    "phone_number": "123",
    "address": "yoqneam",
    "image": "http://imgur.com/a/KslOW"
  }
]
```

PS: I also tried to make 2 different queries and combine the JSON and user `array_merge_recursive` but I got 2 subs arrays instead of a single one

Comment: What is messed up here?

Comment: @jyotimishra im getting the everything after user_id is the same

Comment: Can you please show you table structure with some dummy data, so that it will be easy to create query for you.

Comment: Also try to change " ON user_in_event.event_id = '".$event_id."' " => " ON user_in_event.event_id = user.event_id  where user_in_event.event_id = '".$event_id."' "

Comment: @jyotimishra there are links to the tables as there are

Comment: @jyotimishra also, there's no event_id in user table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try :

```
SELECT user_in_event.role, user_in_event.user_id, user.name, user.email
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_in_event ON user_in_event.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE user_in_event.event_id =25
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here event_id is static. run this query to your database and let me know.